# Why is firebase.database not a function?

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase

Im new in firebase and I have not solved this problem yet,
it says Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

javascript:

```js
 // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBl6dxSW4r1k1x6-BJ7GyiIMkqMsP5zTSA",
    authDomain: "tyui-21cb8.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "tyui-21cb8",
    storageBucket: "tyui-21cb8.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "543804913935",
    appId: "1:543804913935:web:33dd95ec68ab53b810e67a"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  console.log(firebase);

  var database = firebase.database();
```

```html
html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ske.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to importing Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) with

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

you need to add the imports for the Firebase products that you want to use. In your case it should be:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn_1) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

> ```
>  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
>  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
> ```

Which says:

> Realtime Database
>
> ```
> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
> ```